# Merging of xml files java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I have two different xml files described as below and want to merge these xml files and get the expected output may be using xpath or dom parsing but not XSLT since the xmls are always not the same

XML1.xml

```
<personinfo>
   <person>
     <name><name>
     <age></age>
     <address>
     <street></street>
     <city></city>
     <address>
   </person>
   <person>
     <name><name>
     <age></age>
     <address>
     <street></street>
     <city></city>
     <address>
   </person>
   <person>
     <name><name>
     <age></age>
     <address>
     <street></street>
     <city></city>
     <address>
   </person>
</personinfo>
```

XML2.xml

```
<personinfo>
   <person>
     <name>tom<name>
     <age>26</age>
     <address>
     <street>main street</street>
     <city>washington</city>
     <address>
   </person>
   <person>
     <name>mike<name>
     <age>30</age>
     <address>
     <street>first street</street>
     <city>dallas</city>
     <address>
   </person>
</personinfo>
```

Expected.xml

```
<personinfo>
   <person>
     <name>tom<name>
     <age>26</age>
     <address>
     <street>main street</street>
     <city>washington</city>
     <address>
   </person>
   <person>
     <name>mike<name>
     <age>30</age>
     <address>
     <street>first street</street>
     <city>dallas</city>
     <address>
   </person>
   <person>
     <name><name>
     <age></age>
     <address>
     <street></street>
     <city></city>
     <address>
   </person>
</personinfo>
```

Thanks in advance ....

Comment: There's more going on here than just merging.  The first file has three empty `<person>` elements but the output has only one.  How do you decide what to keep and what to delete?  Also the statement "not XSLT since the xmls are always not the same" doesn't quite make sense.  Can you explain further why you believe XSLT is not appropriate?

Comment: If you have a look at the first xml there are three person tags and the second one has two person tags ... all i was trying to do was populate the values from second xml into the template of the first one .... I was not willing to use XSLT because the template xml (first one) is generated on the go , so i don't have a mechanisn which can auto generate the XSLT ..

Comment: Don't think that you need to "auto generate" the XSLT even if your input changes. You could build a general stylesheet which performs the same action on different XML files. This if you just want merge empty nodes as described in your comment.

Comment: I don't have an idea how to achieve that ... can you please help me out ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the flexibility to create a new xml file, you can parse each of them using any parser you are comfortable with. Store the tags in a LinkedList of String LinkedLists and the tag values in a HashMap of the following type:
LinkedHashMap data= new LinkedHashMap();

You can then call the tag names from the linked lists, append the tag values from the Hash Map and write them out to a new XML file.
When I did merging of XMLs, this was the procedure I used. 
Hope this helps

Comment: ya i was kind of trying some thing similar to this but i couldn't get it working ... it would be much helpful if you can post some code ...

Answer (score 0):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(file);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) 
{
stkey=getXMLData(s,nodeLst,"id");
     keylist.add(stkey);// adding integer keys to a Linked List
data.put(stkey, stkey);                 
data.put(stkey+"first",getXMLData(s,nodeLst,"firstname"));                  
data.put(stkey+"last",getXMLData(s,nodeLst,"lastname"));                    
     data.put(stkey+"loc",getXMLData(s,nodeLst,"location"));    
     data.put(stkey+"occ",getXMLData(s,nodeLst,"occupation"));

}
```

this will get the tag values in the hash map and the tag names in the linked list. to make your work easier, you can append the type of tag to the hashmap key. For example: if my key is the Employee ID(in my case), I append "first" to it. Lets say some one has an id: 10001. his data would be stored as: 10001, then 10001first, 10001last, 10001loc,10001occ. Now, you can call each hashmap key, get the element as per appended tag name and concatenate to your xml file.
Hope this helps.